# Is storage in Openshift Online free tier actually persistent?

Tags: openshift

I'm trying to migrate an Openshift v2 application to v3.  I'm really struggling to understand the documentation.  In the [section on persistent volumes](https://docs.openshift.com/online/architecture/additional_concepts/storage.html#pv-restrictions), it says the following:

- EmptyDir has the same lifecycle as the pod:

  - EmptyDir volumes survive container crashes/restarts.
  - EmptyDir volumes are deleted when the pod is deleted.

I cannot understand what this means.  I have added storage to my app using the Web Console, which allowed me to add 1 GB of persistent storage and give it to a particular mountpoint.  I don't know if this is an "EmptyDir" volume or not (I think it isn't, but in that case why the warning in the persistent volumes section?).  Now, every time I rebuild the application, a new pod is created (if I understand this correctly).  So far my data has persisted when this happens. Does this warning mean it can suddenly be wiped out?  Or is persistent storage persistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you claim a persistent volume, you are not usually using an EmptyDir volume type, so that isn't relevant. EmptyDir is a special volume type that is managed a bit differently that would normally only be needed if you want to share some temporary file system space between different containers in the same pod.

Answer (score 1):

In short, the persistent storage is indeed 'persistent'. You could see the difference by a simple experiment of creating a mysql with "non-persistent" vs "persistent".

The openshift architecture is built on Amazon infrastructure. Please check AWS EBS volume which is backbone of Openshift persistent storage -
https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/getting-started/

### EDIT

Think it like that

**EBS Volume -- ATTACHED TO --- pod ---- WHICH CONTAINS --- Containers**

What document means to say that, if you destroy the POD (think of a machine), the EBS volume will be wiped out and available again as an unattached resource. Its lifecycle limited by pod. However, a POD can contain multiple containers (say JVM) and each container can share the EBS volume (think of a hard disk), but killing a container does not affect the EBS lifecycle.

Comment: Yes, but given that the container is recreated when the app is rebuilt, doesn't the warning in the docs mean that the storage will also be wiped?  So far that hasn't happened in my system, but in that case I wonder what the point of that warning is - what is it supposed to mean?

Comment: Added more details, hope it helps